# why does map_if() not work within a list

Tags: r, dictionary, if-statement, purrr

Please help me

1) Why does map_if not work within a list
2) Is there a way to make it work
3) If not, what are the alternatives

Thanks in advance.

```
library(dplyr) 
library(purrr) 

cyl <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl) 

# This works
map_if(mtcars, is.numeric, mean) 

# This does not work 
map_if(cyl, is.numeric, mean)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you need to map to one lever lower, the columns are at level 2. So you can do:

```
map(cyl, ~map_if(., is.numeric, mean))
```

Or:

```
map(cyl, map_if, is.numeric, mean)
```

Without the if one could do

```
map_depth(cyl, 2, mean)
```

Comment: thank you soooo much. I tried map(cyl, map_if(is.numeric, mean)), I came so close. It is super clear to me now. This will make life that much easy. Thank you once again!

Comment: One more option added.

Comment: Update: `at_depth()` is defunct, use `map_depth()` instead

Answer (score 3):

You can try `lapply`:

```
lapply(cyl, function(x) map_if(x, is.numeric, mean))
```

You are attempting to use `map_if()` over a `list` of `data.frames`. The predicate will be tested against each `data.frame`, rather than each column of the data.frame e.g.

```
is.numeric( cyl[[1]] )
#  [1] FALSE
```

And that is because...

```
is.data.frame( cyl[[1]] )
#  [1] TRUE
```

Comment: works like magic! Thanks a ton. I tried without success  "map(map_if(cyl, is.numeric, mean))"

Comment: Thanks @count. The examples make it super clear in my mind! You guys are fab.

Comment: @cephalopod The credit for the example goes to @Simon O`Hanlon, I only prvided the code ;)

Answer (score 0):

`map_if(cyl, is.numeric, mean) %>%as_tibble()`
This is pipable for plotting, summarizing, mutating, etc.