# lapply function to compute means of data frames inside a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, sapply

I am trying to compute means of data frames inside a list using lapply function.

```
df_list <- list(cars, mtcars)
sapply(df_list, mean)
```

The above code doesn't seem to work. However when i changed it to:

```
 df_list <- c(cars, mtcars)
 sapply(df_list, mean)
```

The output had the means of all the variables of both data frames.

is there a way to compute the means using the first approach.

Comment: `c(cars, mtcars)` creates a list with each element from each column, while `list(cars, mtcars)` creates a list with two data frames. Since `mean(mtcars)` or `mean(cars)` result in `NA`, of course the first apporach will not work. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `purrr` library to achieve this...much simpler:

```
library(purrr) 
map(df_list, ~map_if(., is.numeric, mean))
```

If you want a df to be returned then:

```
map_df(df_list, ~map_if(., is.numeric, mean))
```

answer is from here:
[why does map_if() not work within a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42782306/why-does-map-if-not-work-within-a-list/42782889#42782889)
credit should go to @Axeman

Answer (score 2):

In base R, you can use `rapply` in order to calculate the means of variables contained in a list of data.frames.

```
# data
df_list <- list(cars, mtcars)
```

The simplest output is to run `rapply` with two arguments, the function and the list of data.frames. The function `if(is.numeric(x)) mean(x)` checks if the variable is numeric, and if so, returns the mean.

```
# returns a vector of means
rapply(df_list, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) mean(x))
```

This output destroys the relationship between the variables and their data.frames. If desired, we can return the values in a structure that preserves that of the original object, a nested list of length 2 and inner lists of length 2 and 11.

```
rapply(df_list, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) mean(x), how="list")
```

The resulting structure is probably more complicated than desired. For my taste,

```
lapply(rapply(df_list, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) mean(x), how="list"), unlist)
[[1]]
speed  dist 
15.40 42.98 

[[2]]
       mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec 
 20.090625   6.187500 230.721875 146.687500   3.596563   3.217250  17.848750 
        vs         am       gear       carb 
  0.437500   0.406250   3.687500   2.812500
```

results in a nice balance, a list of length 2 each containing named vectors of the means.